# insert new chunk in Rstudio 2023.03.0

Tags: r, rstudio

I have tried to insert new chunk in RStudio using `Ctrl+Alt+I` but am unable to...

Am using

`RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom" Release (3c53477afb13ab959aeb5b34df1f10c237b256c3, 2023-03-09) for Windows Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.0+386 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36`

Comment: What kind of file are you in? Rmd, qmd, ? Just checking, because if you're in a normal R script there are no chunks.

Comment: I am in Rmd file

Comment: Are there any other details you can include in your question that might help people understand your situation? Have you previously been able to insert chunks with that shortcut? Have you adjusted any shortcuts or changed any settings recently?

Comment: I installed Rstudio on a new machine and yes I have been using the shortcut for ages...